# Error occured when sending message through Google Play Game Service with Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, google-play-games

I'm developing a multiplayer game with Google Play Services and Cocos2d-x. I already set up communication between Java and C++ using `JNI`, and can run processes like Sign-in, Create room, Invitation... Everything is fine until I need to send some `struct` to another players. When receive data from other, an error has occurred.
Here's the structs:

```
typedef enum
{
    MESSAGE_TYPE_PING = -1,
    MESSAGE_TYPE_PING_BACK = 0,
    MESSAGE_TYPE_RTT = 3
} MESSAGE_TYPE;

typedef struct
{
    MESSAGE_TYPE messType;
} MESSAGE;

typedef struct
{
    MESSAGE mess;
    timeval sendTime;
    const char* text;
} PING_MESSAGE;
```

And in this code snippet I convert `struct` and send it to another players:

```
void MyClass::sendData()
{
    // Send package
    PING_MESSAGE ping;
    ping.mess.messType = MESSAGE_TYPE_PING;
    ping.sendTime = startTime;
    ping.text = "Ohhhhhh";

    char byte[sizeof(ping)];

    memcpy(byte, &ping, sizeof(ping));

    GCHelper::sendReliableRealTimeMessage(&byte[0]);
}

// In GCHelper's implementation
void GCHelper::sendReliableRealTimeMessage(const char* byteMess)
{        
    // Convert char* to jbyteArray
    jbyteArray bArray = env->NewByteArray(16); //env is a static JNIEnv* in this class; 16 since my PING_MESSAGE struct is 16 bytes in size;
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bArray,0,16,(jbyte*)byteMess);

    // Make Java call
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(classID, methodID, bArray);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(bArray);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(classID);
}
```

Now, Java code take responsibility to send the byte array to participants in room. At receiver side, I'm continue send received data to C++. And error occured here when I convert `jbyteArray` back to `struct`:

```
void Java_package_name_TestMulti_nativeOnRealTimeMessageReceived(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray receivedMess)
{
    CCLOG("Called from java");

    jboolean isCopy;
    jbyte * pCData = env->GetByteArrayElements(receivedMess, &isCopy);
    jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(receivedMess);
    const char* sd = (const char*)pCData;

    PING_MESSAGE result;
    memcpy(&result, sd, sizeof(result));

    CCLOG("TEST size: %d", size);                   // This log out: "TEST size: 16"
    CCLOG("TEST type: %d", result.mess.messType);   // This log out: "TEST type: -1"
    CCLOG("TEST text: %s", result.text);            // AND ERROR!!!!!!!

    cocos2d::CCByteArray* data = cocos2d::CCByteArray::createWithData(sd);
    cocos2d::CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("onRealTimeMessageReceived", data);
    if(isCopy)
    {
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(receivedMess,pCData,JNI_ABORT);
    }
}
```

I'm not understand here. If I don't send byte array to another players yet send that array back to C++ by calling `nativeOnRealTimeMessageReceived()` method from Java side, it runs fine and logs correctly. It's mean that with the same `byte[]` package converted from `char*` in C++, if I just pass it back to C++, it's correct, but if I send it through Google Play Game Services, it goes wrong. What does this mean?